# Creating an instance of Guava Stopwatch with an existing duration

Tags: java, guava

We are using Guava `Stopwatch` to time certain blocks of code in our project.

We have come across a situation where this timing will happen in an external, closed-source component. We are able to extract the timing in a millisecond format, but would still like to use `Stopwatch`'s `toString()` to format the data in order to maintain a standard no matter the source of the timing.

However, `toString()` obviously bases itself on `Stopwatch`'s internal state, and the methods that actually do the formatting (`chooseUnit()` and `abbreviate()`) are `private`.

The only way I have found to achieve what we want is the following - is there a better way?

```
String executeTimeAsString = Stopwatch.createStarted(new Ticker() {

    boolean firstRead = true;

    @Override
    public long read() {
        if (firstRead) {
            firstRead = false;
            return 0L;
        }
        return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(durationInMilliseconds);
    }
}).stop().toString();
```

We are using Guava 18.0.

---

In response to @RC: I could just copy the methods - it's all opensource after all. But it means duplicating code, which isn't great for maintenance, and all the code that currently uses `Stopwatch` would either need migrating to this new utility method, or would remain on `Stopwatch`. Which is fine until Google change the `toString()` method of `Stopwatch`.

Comment: What do you mean by better? (You could copy `toString`, `chooseUnit` and `abbreviate` in a "Formatting" class that can format either a stopwatch or some duration.)

Comment: Better in the sense that I'm not doing what I've found - it seems a bit strange, and I was under the impression that the Ticker was mainly for testing.

Comment: "Too bad this functionality is not exposed as a regular method call" ([guava/Stopwatch.java:215](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/15950e79dfe33c36051c58441d7fda9d74509677/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.java#L215)).

I suggest creating a new issue at [Issues · google/guava](https://github.com/google/guava/issues) for doing so.

There are some related existing issues (e.g. [TimeSpan (TimeUnit + long) class · Issue #631 · google/guava](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/631)) but all you want is something like a static `toString` method and not a new `TimeSpan` class, etc.